# Annotation Processing in GWT with Maven

Tags: android, gwt, maven, requestfactory

I am trying to get my android application to communicate with the server using the same requestfactories my gwt app does. I use maven to build both the android app and the gwt app. 
On android when a request-factory call is made I get the exception:

```
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839): java.lang.RuntimeException: No token manifest found.  Did the RequestFactory annotation processor run? Check classpath for META-INF/requestFactory/typeTokens file and ensure that your proxy types are compiled with the requestfactory-apt.jar on javac's classpath.
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.TypeTokenResolver.loadFromClasspath(TypeTokenResolver.java:104)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InProcessRequestFactory.<init>(InProcessRequestFactory.java:82)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.RequestFactorySource.create(RequestFactorySource.java:43)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.myproject.core.android.helper.Util.getRequestFactory(Util.java:97)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.myproject.core.android.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:54)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2501)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9107)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-05 23:04:33.501: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use java 1.6 for building.My gwt version is 2.4 (rc1). I tried using the maven-processor-plugin and imported requestfactory-apt. But somehow the maven processor-plugin doesn't seem to find a processor. Not sure how the configuration should look.

I have:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>process</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase> 
          <<configuration>
            <processors>
               <processor>com.google.gwt.requestfactory-apt</processor>
            </processors> 
          </configuration>  
        </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

The folder for annotations is created in my target folder but it is empty. Does anybody know what the problem could be? What other information do you need?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the version to 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT. Now I get :

```
[INFO] Source directory: E:\Eclipse\Eclipse3.7\android\target\META-INF\requestFactory added
[INFO] javac option: -cp
[INFO] javac option: C:\profiles\....
[INFO] javac option: -proc:only
[INFO] javac option: -processor
[INFO] javac option: com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfApt
[INFO] javac option: -d
[INFO] javac option: E:\Eclipse\Eclipse3.7\android\target\classes
[INFO] javac option: -s
[INFO] javac option: E:\Eclipse\Eclipse3.7\android\target\META-INF\requestFactory
```

but there are no files in this folder. When I add:

```
<compilerArguments>
             -Averbose=true</compilerArguments>   
          </configuration>
```

to my pom. I get the error-message:

```
diagnostic warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[verbose]'
```

Now I am stuck again :-/

Answer (score 0):

The name of the processor class is `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfApt`, however it should be automatically discovered without the need for the explicit `<configuration>` section.

Also, you have `<<configuration>` in the sample code, is that a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: actually I had <<configuration but it doesn't change anything :-/ what I find weird is that even when I use the configuration part I am getting the message : No processors specified. Using default discovery mechanism. And it doesn't discover anything. Tried it with the processor class above.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,
[RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation)

Try using the RequestFactory ValidationTool

Comment: thanks. Tried it and it doesn't really help. But I think the problem is my multiproject setup. I have different project where I have my services and proxies. I opened another post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718320/requestfactory-validation-on-multi-project-setup